# Largest known multi-perfect number (excluding perfect numbers)

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

What is the largest known multi-perfect number (excluding the perfect numbers) ?

[2, 94; 3, 32; 5, 9; 7, 11; 11, 2; 13, 8; 17, 1; 19, 5; 23, 1; 29, 2; 31, 2; 37,
 1; 43, 1; 53, 1; 59, 1; 61, 2; 67, 1; 71, 1; 73, 1; 83, 3; 97, 1; 107, 1; 127,
1; 181, 1; 191, 2; 331, 1; 353, 1; 487, 1; 521, 1; 607, 1; 1493, 1; 2609, 1; 385
1, 1; 5347, 1; 160967, 1; 524287, 1; 547889, 1; 1609669, 1; 2908363, 1; 6491257,
 1; 420778751, 1; 947723521, 1; 2413941289, 1; 30327152671, 1]

is a very large $8$-perfect number which was given in the answer to this question :

[Number $N>6$, such that $N-1$ and $N+1$ are primes and $N$ divides the sum of its divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271194/number-n6-such-that-n-1-and-n1-are-primes-and-n-divides-the-sum-of-it)

- Is this the largest known multi-perfect number which is not perfect ?

Comment: Why do you clone your post? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272132/largest-known-multi-perfect-number-excluding-perfect-numbers

Comment: I added the link and accidentically copied the question, but the error is fixed now.

Comment: The question you link to contains a link to http://oeis.org/A007691/b007691.txt where the number whose factorization you gave is 1121 out of 1600 entries.  (It was singled out because $N-1$ and $N+1$ are both primes, but you don't seem to be requiring that here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the requirement that $N-1$ and $N+1$ are primes, just that $N$ divides $\sigma(N)$, a quick search via Google for "largest known multiperfect number" gives the [Multiperfect Number page from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiperfectNumber.html), where it is stated that:

> Moxham (2000) found the largest known multiperfect number, approximately equal to $7.3 \times {10}^{1345}$, on February 13, 2000.

Obviously, that number is **VERY BIG**.